# Why is another figure being drawn?

Tags: c#

The following code gives the correct picture

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;

namespace RefactorMe
{
    internal class Painter
    {
        private static float x, y;
        private static Graphics graph;

        public static void Initialization(Graphics newGraph)
        {
            graph = newGraph;
            graph.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.None;
            graph.Clear(Color.Black);
        }

        public static void Set_position(float x0, float y0)
        { x = x0; y = y0; }

        public static void MakeIt(Pen pen, double lenght, double angle)
        {
            //Takes a step of length lenght in the direction of angle and draws the passed trajectory
            float x1 = (float)(x + (lenght * Math.Cos(angle)));
            float y1 = (float)(y + (lenght * Math.Sin(angle)));
            graph.DrawLine(pen, x, y, x1, y1);
            x = x1;
            y = y1;
        }

        public static void Change(double lenght, double angle)
        {
            x = (float)(x + (lenght * Math.Cos(angle)));
            y = (float)(y + (lenght * Math.Sin(angle)));
        }
    }

    public class ImpossibleSquare
    {
        public static void Draw(int width, int height, double turnAngle, Graphics graph)
        {
            // turnAngle is not used yet, but will be used in the future
            Painter.Initialization(graph);

            var size = Math.Min(width, height);

            var diagonal_length = Math.Sqrt(2) * (size * 0.375f + size * 0.04f) / 2;
            var x0 = (float)(diagonal_length * Math.Cos(Math.PI / 4 + Math.PI)) + width / 2f;
            var y0 = (float)(diagonal_length * Math.Sin(Math.PI / 4 + Math.PI)) + height / 2f;

            Painter.Set_position(x0, y0);
            //Draws 1st side
            Painter.MakeIt(Pens.Yellow, size * 0.375f, 0);
            Painter.MakeIt(Pens.Yellow, size * 0.04f * Math.Sqrt(2), Math.PI / 4);
            Painter.MakeIt(Pens.Yellow, size * 0.375f, Math.PI);
            Painter.MakeIt(Pens.Yellow, size * 0.375f - size * 0.04f, Math.PI / 2);

            Painter.Change(size * 0.04f, -Math.PI);
            Painter.Change(size * 0.04f * Math.Sqrt(2), 3 * Math.PI / 4);
            
            //Draws 2nd side
            Painter.MakeIt(Pens.Yellow, size * 0.375f, -Math.PI / 2);
            Painter.MakeIt(Pens.Yellow, size * 0.04f * Math.Sqrt(2), -Math.PI / 2 + Math.PI / 4);
            Painter.MakeIt(Pens.Yellow, size * 0.375f, -Math.PI / 2 + Math.PI);
            Painter.MakeIt(Pens.Yellow, size * 0.375f - size * 0.04f, -Math.PI / 2 + Math.PI / 2);

            Painter.Change(size * 0.04f, -Math.PI / 2 - Math.PI);
            Painter.Change(size * 0.04f * Math.Sqrt(2), -Math.PI / 2 + 3 * Math.PI / 4);

            //Draws 3rd side
            Painter.MakeIt(Pens.Yellow, size * 0.375f, Math.PI);
            Painter.MakeIt(Pens.Yellow, size * 0.04f * Math.Sqrt(2), Math.PI + Math.PI / 4);
            Painter.MakeIt(Pens.Yellow, size * 0.375f, Math.PI + Math.PI);
            Painter.MakeIt(Pens.Yellow, size * 0.375f - size * 0.04f, Math.PI + Math.PI / 2);

            Painter.Change(size * 0.04f, Math.PI - Math.PI);
            Painter.Change(size * 0.04f * Math.Sqrt(2), Math.PI + 3 * Math.PI / 4);

            //Draws 4th side
            Painter.MakeIt(Pens.Yellow, size * 0.375f, Math.PI / 2);
            Painter.MakeIt(Pens.Yellow, size * 0.04f * Math.Sqrt(2), Math.PI / 2 + Math.PI / 4);
            Painter.MakeIt(Pens.Yellow, size * 0.375f, Math.PI / 2 + Math.PI);
            Painter.MakeIt(Pens.Yellow, size * 0.375f - size * 0.04f, Math.PI / 2 + Math.PI / 2);

            Painter.Change(size * 0.04f, Math.PI / 2 - Math.PI);
            Painter.Change(size * 0.04f * Math.Sqrt(2), Math.PI / 2 + 3 * Math.PI / 4);
        }
    }
}
```

Right Drawing:
[image]

I tried to change the way the sides are drawn to shorten the code.

```
    for (int side = -1; side < 3; side++)
            {
            
            Painter.MakeIt(Pens.Yellow, size * 0.375f, (side * Math.PI / 2));
            Painter.MakeIt(Pens.Yellow, size * 0.04f * Math.Sqrt(2), (side * Math.PI / 2) + Math.PI / 4);
            Painter.MakeIt(Pens.Yellow, size * 0.375f, (side * Math.PI / 2) + Math.PI);
            Painter.MakeIt(Pens.Yellow, size * 0.375f - size * 0.04f, (side * Math.PI / 2) + Math.PI / 2);

            Painter.Change(size * 0.04f, (side * Math.PI / 2) - Math.PI);
            Painter.Change(size * 0.04f * Math.Sqrt(2), (side * Math.PI / 2) + (3 * Math.PI / 4));
            }
```

The same thing should be built, only in a different order (2, 1, 4, 3), but the sides of the square are drawn in the wrong places and I don't know why

Wrong Drawing:
[image]

*How do I change the code so that the correct shape is drawn?*

Comment: You would need to debug your changes to see where it is going wrong. Microsoft create a nice [Tutorial: Learn to debug C# code using Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/get-started/csharp/tutorial-debugger?view=vs-2022) on this subject

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/. Did you try to figure out what is going on by **watching** what goes on, step by step? For example, by making the program wait for user input before each line, or by using a debugger to break the program when it is about to draw a line, and checking the values of variables at that point?

Comment: Do you see how the wrong drawing is *related to* the correct one? It looks to me like it draws pieces of the correct figure, but in the wrong place. Maybe that has something to do with the calculations that involve `side`? Did you try to check the math? Or maybe it has something to do with the initial position of the pen before drawing each part? (Can you think of a rule that tells you, how to move the Painter from the end position of one part, to the start of the next?)

Comment: @KarlKnechtel
>it has something to do with the initial position of the pen before drawing each part
Probably that's the point. I'm trying to check the 'Change' module rn

Comment: Not an actual answer but can help the debugging: you can use [this](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=KGySoft.drawing-debugger-visualizers) debugger visualizer (disclaimer: written by me) to see what is actually drawn on the `Graphics` step by step.

Answer (score 0):

Change this function:

```
public static void MakeIt(Pen pen, double lenght, double angle)
{
  //Takes a step of length lenght in the direction of angle and draws the passed trajectory
  float x1 = (float)(x + (lenght * Math.Cos(angle)));
  float y1 = (float)(y + (lenght * Math.Sin(angle)));
  graph.DrawLine(pen, x, y, x1, y1);
  x = x1;
  y = y1;
}
```

... into:

```
public static void MakeIt(Pen pen, double lenght, double angle)
{
  //Takes a step of length lenght in the direction of angle and draws the passed trajectory
  float x1 = (float)(x + (lenght * Math.Cos(angle)));
  float y1 = (float)(y + (lenght * Math.Sin(angle)));
  graph.DrawLine(pen, x, y, x1, y1);
  Write_to_output(pen, x, y, x1, y1);
  x = x1;
  y = y1;
}
```

... and investigate the values of all variables, needed for this. I would personally advise not to start reading that output, but you to try to guess what the output will be first, and only then you verify the generated output by your guessing. Like this, you have a better chance of finding errors.